# Who Given Weapons to Gods?

Tags: gods

who Given Weapons (like trisulam, sudharshana chakram, brahma creation) Gods and goddesses.Weapons Power?

Other gods like sun, moon,indra etc., there powers?

Comment: how they get powers? like there weapons

Comment: The weapons are just the physical representation of their powers. The powers represented by the gods are merely through their knowledge which they got from their Gurus and boons from other counterparts.